# Can't launch lightbox from miithril View

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I'm new to Mithril and trying to wrap my head around this issue.

I have a view that creates a DOM element and has a onClick method declared. Unfortunately when I tried to launch a lightbox such as magnificPopup, jqueryui dialog, fancybox or you name it, it calls the method undefined, even though the lightbox library is loaded.

Is this an issue with Mithril?

Here is my code:

```
        m('a.view-link', {
          onclick: function() { 

          $.colorbox();  // this fails
          alert('here is the code'); // alerts do work
          $('.view-link').css('border', '2px solid red'); // this works

          // $('.white-popup').magnificPopup({  // this claims .magnificPopup is undefined
          //   type:'inline',
          //   midClick: true
          // });

          //     $('#dialog').dialog('open'); //jqueryUI dialog claims that .dialog is undefined

          },  
         href: '#' 
        } , ' Show link in lightbox')
```

Answer (score 2):

The way Mithril works is by creating a virtual DOM (i.e. a plain-javascript data structure that represents a template), and then rendering this virtual DOM to create a real DOM tree.

When you call `m()`, you're building this virtual DOM, so at that point the DOM elements don't exist yet in the document. In order to integrate third party libraries, the correct way to do it is via the `config` attribute (see http://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.html#accessing-the-real-dom-element )

In a nutshell, the `config` function gets called after rendering, and it takes the element as an argument, along with some other parameters to help control its lifecycle.

The syntax looks like this:

```
m("a.view-link", {config: function(el) {
  $(el).colorbox() //initialize jquery plugin
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Might it be that `$.colorbox();` is missing the 'subject' element?

`$(this).colorbox();` should work better.